# When I type text inside the text field, the text appears after a while

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have created 3 to 4 projects in React JS, in all projects I have used text field Material UI with Formik.

All those text fields are displayed after some time when I write text, and after some time I delete the text.

How can I solve this problem?

```
// My text field inside the form
<TextField
  fullWidth
  type="number"
  size="small"
  placeholder="MobileNumber"
  label="MobileNumber"
  name="mobileNumber"
  className="col-sm-10"
  value={partyFormik.values.mobileNumber}
  onBlur={partyFormik.handleBlur}
  onChange={partyFormik.handleChange}
/>
{partyFormik.touched.mobileNumber &&
  partyFormik.errors.mobileNumber ? (
  <div className="text-danger">
    {partyFormik.errors.mobileNumber}
  </div>
  ) : null
}

// I want output like this
```

I want the text to appear immediately inside the text field as I type

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this is unclear whether after releasing button _and doing nothing else_ character appears later. Or as it's named typing is "one step behind" when only after pressing next key makes previous character to appear. And even after you clarify this, given snippet does not have any base for answer, unfortunately.